# Can i set float128 as the standard float-array in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, types

So I have a problem with my numerical program, and I'm curious about whether it is a precision problem (i.e. round-off error). Is there a quick way to change all the float arrays in my program into `float128` arrays, without going through my code and typing `dtype='float128'` all over the place. My arrays are all float64, but i never explicitly wrote `dtype='float64'`, so i was hoping there was a way to change this default behavior.

Comment: There is a `numpy.float_` constant set to `float64`, but changing it to `numpy.float128` and asking `numpy.array([1.1]).dtype` keeps returning `float64`.

Comment: The support for float128 is sketchy, irc it won't work with windows. Try the same with float96.

Comment: I'm working a Linux (Ubuntu) system. How is the support there? The fact that it won't work on windows doesn't really matter since it is just a check for myself.

Comment: Late reply, but the better solution here is to use `numpy.longdouble`, which goes to `float128` on linux and `float96` on windows.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I don't think there is a central "configuration" you could change to achieve this.  Some options what you could do:

1. If you are creating arrays only by very few of NumPy's factory functions, substitute these functions by your own versions.  If you import these functions like

   ```
   from numpy import empty
   ```

   you can just do

   ```
   from numpy import float128, empty as _empty
   def empty(*args, **kwargs):
       kwargs.update(dtype=float128)
       _empty(*args, **kwargs)
   ```

   If you are doing

   ```
   import numpy
   ```

   you can write a module `mynumpy.py`

   ```
   from numpy import *
   _empty = empty
   def empty(*args, **kwargs):
       kwargs.update(dtype=float128)
       _empty(*args, **kwargs)
   ```

   and import it like

   ```
   import mynumpy as numpy
   ```
2. Refactor your code to always use `dtype=myfloat`.  This will make such changes easy in the future.  You can combine this approach with the use of `numpy.empty_like()`, `numpy.zeros_like()` and `numpy.ones_like()` wherever appropriate to have the actual data type hardcoded in as few places as possible.
3. Sub-class `numpy.ndarray` and only use your custom constructors to create new arrays.

Comment: Trying these in order is probably best: 1-2-3.  The last option (Sub-classing `numpy.ndarray`) is elegant, but there are pitfalls.  For example, I accidentally broke array garbage collection by storing slices of the array as attributes, i.e. `self.myslice = self[0, :]`.  My RAM would slowly fill up as I did more and more operations.