# Inconvenience to use single precision floats in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, floating-point, precision

When writing code using single precision (`float32`) in numpy, it is too hard to write.

First, the decalartion of single presion float is too long. We have to type all variables as follows.

```
a = np.float32(5)
```

But some other language use simpler representation.

```
a = 5.f
```

Second, arthemetic operations are also inconvenient.

```
b = np.int32(5)+np.float32(5)
```

I expected the type of `b` is `numpy.float32` but it is `numpy.float64`.

Of course,

```
b = np.add(np.int32(5), np.float32(5), dtype=np.float32)
```

returns what I want. But it is too long to replace all operations.

Are there any simpler way to use single precision in numpy?

Comment: Why on Earth would you assume that `b` is an instance of `float32`?

Comment: Sorry, it is mistake. np.int32(5) is correct. I'll modify soon.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: Making numpy default to float32](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5721831/python-making-numpy-default-to-float32)

Comment: No, I already read that question. Of course, it is best way to solve my problem if possible. But it isn't. So, I just look for easy way to use single precision in numpy.

Comment: numpy is not really the right tool to statically type python code. Going for cython is probably a better idea.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that NumPy promotes the types when you use different types in an operation. `float32` only stays `float32` if the other numeric operand has a dtype of:

- `float32` or less
- `int16` or less
- `uint16` or less

If the other operand has another dtype the result will be `float64` (or `complex` if the other operand is complex). The dtypes listed above aren't the most common ones so almost any operation (especially when the other is a Python integer/float) using the standard operators `+`, `-`, `/`, `*`, ... will promote your `float32` to `float64`.

Unfortunately there's not much you can do to avoid that. In lots of the cases it's okay that NumPy does that because:

- Most architectures can process double precision as fast as single precision floats. Arithmetic operations in Python work fast on Python types but slower on others.

```
import numpy as np
a32 = np.float32(1)
a64 = np.float64(1)
a = 1.
%timeit [a32 + a32 for _ in range(20000)]  # 100 loops, best of 3: 4.58 ms per loop
%timeit [a64 + a64 for _ in range(20000)]  # 100 loops, best of 3: 4.83 ms per loop
%timeit [a + a for _ in range(20000)]      # 100 loops, best of 3: 2.72 ms per loop
```

- Python types have so much overhead that the memory overhead of **scalar** double precision floats is almost negligible.

```
import sys
import numpy as np
    
sys.getsizeof(np.float32(1))  # 28
sys.getsizeof(np.float64(1))  # 32
sys.getsizeof(1.)             # 24  # that's also a double on my computer!
```

However it makes sense to use single precision floats if you have huge arrays and you run into memory problems otherwise, or if you interact with other libraries that expect single precision floats (machine-learning, GPU, ...).

But as mentioned above you'll almost always fight against the coercion rules, which prevent you from running into unexpected problems.

The example with `int32 + float32` is actually a great example! You expect the result to be `float32` - but there is a problem: you can't represent the every `int32` as `float32`:

```
np.iinfo(np.int32(1))             # iinfo(min=-2147483648, max=2147483647, dtype=int32)
int(np.float32(2147483647))       # 2147483648
np.int32(np.float32(2147483647))  # -2147483648
```

Yes, just by converting the value to a single precision float and converting it back to an integer it changed it's value. That's why NumPy uses double precision, so that you don't end up with an **unexpected** result! That's why you need to **force NumPy** to do something that could be wrong (from the general user perspective).

---

Since there's no (as far as I know) way to restrict type promotion with Numpy you have to invent your own.

For example you could create a class that wraps a NumPy array and uses special methods to implement the dtype-d functions for the operators:

```
import numpy as np

class Arr32:
    def __init__(self, arr):
        self.arr = arr
        
    def __add__(self, other):
        other_arr = other
        if isinstance(other, Arr32):
            other_arr = other.arr
        return self.__class__(np.add(self.arr, other_arr, dtype=np.float32))
        
    def __sub__(self, other):
        other_arr = other
        if isinstance(other, Arr32):
            other_arr = other.arr
        return self.__class__(np.subtract(self.arr, other_arr, dtype=np.float32))
        
    def __mul__(self, other):
        other_arr = other
        if isinstance(other, Arr32):
            other_arr = other.arr
        return self.__class__(np.multiply(self.arr, other_arr, dtype=np.float32))
        
    def __truediv__(self, other):
        other_arr = other
        if isinstance(other, Arr32):
            other_arr = other.arr
        return self.__class__(np.divide(self.arr, other_arr, dtype=np.float32))
```

But that only implements a small subset of the NumPy functionality and will quickly result in lots of code and edge cases that might have been forgotten. There might be smarter ways nowadays using [`__array_ufunc__`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/neps/ufunc-overrides.html) or [`__array_function__`](https://numpy.org/neps/nep-0018-array-function-protocol.html), but I haven't used these myself so I cannot comment on the amount of work or suitability.

So my preferred solution would be to create helper functions for the function that are needed:

```
import numpy as np

def arr32(a):
    return np.float32(a)

def add32(a1, a2):
    return np.add(a1, a2, dtype=np.float32)

def sub32(a1, a2):
    return np.subtract(a1, a2, dtype=np.float32)

def mul32(a1, a2):
    return np.multiply(a1, a2, dtype=np.float32)

def div32(a1, a2):
    return np.divide(a1, a2, dtype=np.float32)
```

Or only use in-place operations because these won't promote the type:

```
>>> import numpy as np

>>> arr = np.float32([1,2,3])
>>> arr += 2
>>> arr *= 3
>>> arr
array([ 9., 12., 15.], dtype=float32)
```

Comment: "Most architectures can process double precision as fast as single precision floats" I think that's true if you're looking at the time to perform a single operation, but cache locality and the existence of SIMD instructions that handle twice as many float32s as they can handle float64s at once mean that in practice, operations with a `float32` array may well be faster. Trying a `%timeit x + x` for a 1d NumPy array `x` of a million random floats. I get 788 us per loop with `float64`, and 288 us per loop with `float32`. Your results may be different, of course.

Comment: @MarkDickinson Correct, but the question was about scalars and python and there `float32` is seldom (maybe never) a good choice. I didn't go into much detail with whole arrays - but of course `float32` makes sense for arrays (SIMD, memory overhead, memory throughput, GPU). However cache locality is a different story because the memory management of numpy isn't *always* good for cache locality (it can be C or F contiguous or even slightly misaligned if I remember correctly).

Comment: Ah, sorry; yes, I was misreading. Indeed for scalars it's clear. (And agreed that the caching analysis gets messy.)

Comment: I came here looking for a way to emulate the computations of a system that only has single precision. Saying "there is actually no use-case where single precision numpy floats are useful" clearly indicates you didn't think hard enough.

Comment: @Daniele You're definitely right. There are several use-cases for single-precision floats that I haven't thought of when writing the answer (GPU, memory, other libraries). I think it's still complex to prevent NumPy from promoting to double precision floats but saying there's no use-case is clearly wrong. I'll update the answer shortly.

Comment: @Daniele I updated the answer. I hope it's more informative now. Let me know if you think it's still incorrect or misleading.