# How to work in 'float32' mode by default in python?

Tags: python, numpy, floating-point

I am working with 100s of big `.csv` file size of approx 500GB. It is becoming difficult to handle this much of big data so I want to reduce overhead by converting `float64` into `float32`. I had done it explicitly with `astype('float32')` but it is converting back to `float64` after an arithmetic operation.

```
data.dtypes -> dtype('float64')

data32 = data.astype('float32')
data32.dtypes -> dtype('float32')

#after a float operation
data_f = data32*1.01       #######-> I want to keep data type float32 after operation
data_f.dtypes -> dtype('float64')
```

I want to keep the default result in `32-bit mode`. I have found one [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5721831/python-making-numpy-default-to-float32) but it was asked almost a decade ago. I am hoping to get a fix for this so that I can set `32bit` operation globally.

Comment: "Python" just has 64bit double-precision floats, presume you're talking about numpy or even pandas?  could you be more specific, as your example stays with `float32`s using numpy 1.16.4 for me

Comment: Python does not have a `float32` datatype. That is a  `numpy` thing. So when you do `data32*1.01` you are multiplying a `float32` by a normal Python float. To do what you want you will have to do all your arithmetic using `numpy` `float32`s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use pandas to read the csv and specify the type of each columns ; use pandas to write back the csv.
You can also use numpy for (fast) arithmetic operations and specify the dtype float32 that is not available in pure python.