# How do I run numpy/scipy program using one matrix data type

Tags: numpy, memory, scipy

It is possible for me to run numpy/scipy methods using np.float32 rather than np.float64. I'm currently having trouble managing an amount of data larger than my RAM memory and is looking for ways to reduce the size of the data.

Comment: This is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5721831/python-making-numpy-default-to-float32 -- in brief, yes, you can use np.float32; but you have to specify the type yourself when creating the array objects.