# Is there a way of change the default data types in Python?

Tags: python, numpy, custom-data-type

suppose I want the default data type to be `np.uint8`, in such a way that when I call:

```
a = 2
print(type(a))
```

I get in output `numpy.uint8`.

Is it possible to obtain this?

Comment: What would be the objective of such a thing?

Comment: If that *would* be possible, it wouldn't be Python anymore.

Comment: @DanielMesejo : to write a routine that uses less memory, as example

Comment: @VincenzoLavorini If you need to optimize your code so much, that integers are using too much memory, then python is not the correct language to do it.

Comment: You could do `a = np.uint(8)`, if that is too much, you could define an alias for the function, for example: `ui8 = np.uint8;a = ui8(2)`.

Comment: we should remember that explicit is better than implicit, and what you are trying to do is an implicit conversion from Python's `int` to numpy's type

Comment: Don't confuse Python's own integer and float types with `numpy's` dtypes.  `a=2` defines a Python integer.  `type(a)` should not return a numpy type.  `a = np.array([0,2,3], dtype='uint8')` creates an array with an explicit `dtype`.  Your question should be whether `a.dtype` can be `uint8` by default or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible, at least not with little effort, and it was [discouraged](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/6860#issuecomment-165958199) when it was discussed on Numpy's issue tracker as 'unlikely to add', for good reason.

The easiest thing to do is to either use a function that takes the input and casts it to the desired data type or to check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5350342/can-i-set-float128-as-the-standard-float-array-in-numpy/5351486#5351486) post on to 'overload' your `numpy` functions to always use eg. `dtype=uint8`.